# Два условия в Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net

Возможно ли в foreach запихнуть два условия, что бы избежать foreach в foreach?
Пример:

```
foreach(var t in ViewBag.News){
       foreach(var n in ViewBag.Like){
    }
}
```

это превратить в это:

```
 foreach(var t in ViewBag.News && var n in ViewBag.Like){}
```

Весь код страницы:

```
@using WebPhotoArchive.Models
@model IQueryable<Post>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    string Name = null;
    int id_link = 0;
}

@if (ViewBag.News == null)
{
    <p><h3><b>Подпишитесь на других пользователей, чтобы получать их публикации!</b></h3></p>
}
else
{
    foreach (var n in ViewBag.News)
    {
    <div class="row">
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                @{ Name = n.UserDoName; id_link = n.UserDoId;}
                <input type="hidden" name="id_post" value="@n.Id" />
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <h4>@Html.ActionLink(Name, "/UserProfile/" + id_link, "Home", new { @class = "nav navbar-nav", @style = "text-decoration: none; color: #000000;" })</h4>
                </div>
                <hr />
                @Html.Raw("<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(n.Photo) + "\" />") @*для уменьшения добавить в img style='width:300px; height:350px;'*@
                <p><strong>@Name:</strong><i>@n.Description</i></p>
                <div class="btn-group" id="Div1">
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn-group" href="@Url.RouteUrl(new {controller = "Home", action = "LikeSystem", id = n.Id })">
                            @foreach (var t in ViewBag.LikePost)
                            {
                                if (n.Id == t.LikingId)
                                {
                                    <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_2.png" />
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_1.png" />
                                }
                            }
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn-group" href="@Url.RouteUrl(new {controller = "Home", action = "Comment", id_post = n.Id })">
                            <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/comments.png" />
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    }
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult Index()//новости
    {
        #region My Id, variable 'i' for get it
        int i = 0;
        var id = from c in db.Users where c.Login == User.Identity.Name select c.Id;
        foreach (var t in id)
        {
            i = t;
        }
        #endregion
        using (WebArchiveContext dbc = new WebArchiveContext())
        {
            var list_like = dbc.Likes.Where(l => l.LikerId == i);
            ViewBag.LikePost = list_like;
        }
        var news_following_id = db.Follows.Where(u => u.FollowerId == i).Select(u => u.FollowingId);
        IQueryable<Post> list_news = null;
        list_news = db.Posts.Where(u => news_following_id.Contains(u.UserDoId)).OrderByDescending(p => p.Time);
        if (list_news.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.News = list_news;
        }
        else ViewBag.News = null;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: что такое ViewBag.News и что такое ViewBag.Like ?

Comment: @tym32167 Это гипотетически придуманные переменные, Новости и относящиеся к ним лайки.

Comment: тогда какого типа будет переменная `t` здесь? `foreach(var t in ViewBag.News && var t in ViewBag.Like){}`

Comment: Ошибочка, разные переменные должны быть foreach(var t in ViewBag.News && var n in ViewBag.Like){}

Comment: тогда нет, такого синтаксиса нет в C#. Один foreach на одну переменную. А какую вы задачу этим хотите решить?

Comment: Есть система постов, на каждый пост юзер может поставить лайк, когда он ставит лайк, картинка должна меняться на красный лайк, посты у меня выносятся через foreach, с лайками по другому, я сделал проверку и получил лайки которые поставил авторизированный пользователь и через foreach вывожу их, всё работает, но самих картинок лайков становится столько же, сколько и постоав из-за foreach в foreach

Comment: у вас же лайк на пост, то есть картинок и должно быть столько же, сколько постов разве нет?

Comment: Не, вот скрин как должно быть https://imgur.com/a/cDfRlox, но когда ставлю ещё лайки, становится вот так и если поставить лайки на все посты, лайков становится столько же сколько и постов https://imgur.com/a/fLN65TH

Comment: так вам надо фильтровать лайки по постам, что то типа `foreach(var post in ViewBag.News) { foreach(var like in ViewBag.Like.Where(l=>l.PostId == post.Id)){ ...`

Comment: Так у меня есть эта фильтрация, проблема в том, что foreach лайков находится внутри foreach постов, и поэтому при лайках на всех постах, их становится такое же кол-во как постов

Comment: Покажите код вашей страницы (добавьте его в вопрос) а то вы меня запутали

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: Покажите как вы заполняете вот эту коллекцию `ViewBag.LikePost`. На первый взгляд ошибок в коде страницы я не вижу.

Comment: var like_post = db.Likes.Where(l => l.LikerId == i).ToList();
            ViewBag.LikePost = like_post;
i = id авторизированного пользователя

Comment: Проверьте вашу БД. У вас там точно 1 лайк на пост для вашего юзера? Убедитесь, что данные в БД по лайкам и постам корректные

Comment: Данные проверял, они полностью корректные, я же говорю, проблема в том, что foreach находится внутри другого foreach, + проблема с if при выборе картинки, т.к если лайков нет, картинка не заменяется, если бы заменялась, сразу же было бы кол-во картинок равное кол-ву постов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим на ваш цикл

```
@foreach (var t in ViewBag.LikePost)
{
    if (n.Id == t.LikingId)
    {
        <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_2.png" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_1.png" />
    }
}
```

и что видим? Для каждого совпадающего поста вы ставите лайк, а для остальных картинку с отсутсвием лайка. Это неверно, так как для лайков, которые не относятся к посту, вы тоже что то нарисуете.

Как испроавить - заменить вложенный цикл, который вам не нужен, на условие:

```
@if (((IEnumerable<Like>)ViewBag.LikePost).Any(l=>l.LikingId == n.Id))
{
    <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_2.png" />
}
else
{
    <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_1.png" />
}
```

Dummy вариант

```
@{
    bool likeFound = false;

    foreach (var t in ViewBag.LikePost)
    {
        if (n.Id == t.LikingId)
        {
            likeFound = true;
            
            <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_2.png" />

            break;
        }        
    }    

    if (!likeFound)
    {       
        <img style='width:30px; height:30px;' src="~/Content/like_1.png" />        
    }
}
```

Comment: Появилась ошибка: https://imgur.com/a/Uo3NyNG

Comment: Сделал каст в `(IEnumerable<Like>)ViewBag.LikePost)`, где `Like` - ваш класс лайков. Сам не пишу на дотнете уже, потому такие ошибки могу допускать :)

Comment: Ошибка CS0012 Тип "ValueType" определен в сборке, на которую нет ссылки. Следует добавить ссылку на сборку "netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,

Comment: так у вас asp.net core? Вы можете поменять `@if (((IEnumerable<Like>)ViewBag.LikePost).Any(l=>l.LikingId == n.Id))` на `@if (((IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewBag.LikePost).Any(l=>l.LikingId == n.Id))` или [добавить netstandard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/458#issuecomment-323845208) если первое не сработает

Comment: Нет, ASP NET MVC 5
На всякий попробовал это способ - не работает. При добавлении сборки так же ошибки

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант. Хз съест ли это razor, но попробуйте, чем черт не шутит

Comment: Попробовал, выводит следующую ошибку на foreach https://imgur.com/a/W2A2IpE
Заменил в контроллере подключение на using (WebArchiveContext dbc = new WebArchiveContext())
            {
                var list_like = dbc.Likes.Where(l => l.LikerId == i);
                ViewBag.LikePost = list_like;
            }
и уже выбило это https://imgur.com/a/o7VAsBu

Comment: У вас же foreach работал до этого? На какой из них ошибка? На тот, что мы правим? Как вы посты вытягиваете из бд тоже покажите

Comment: `var list_like = dbc.Likes.Where(l => l.LikerId == i).ToList();` всегда добавляйте .ToList() в конце, когда вытягиваете данные из бд

Comment: добавил весь код контроллера

Comment: Вернул на место ToList, всё заработало, большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: на здоровье. Хорошо, что завелось

Answer (score 0):

Давайте не будем возиться со страницами ASP.NET, а используем консольное приложение. Ведь главное - сделать одновременную итерацию по двум коллекциям сразу. Я правильно понял?

Наши гипотетические коллекции:

```
var ViewBagNews = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var ViewBagLike = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Стандартный способ прохода сразу по двум коллекциям, когда их размеры равны. Используем цикл for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ViewBagNews.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBagNews[i] + " " + ViewBagLike[i]);
}
```

Допустим, коллекции не реализуют интерфейс `IList`, поэтому обращение по индексу невозможно.

Используем другой стандартный способ с применением энумераторов:

```
using (var newsEnumerator = ViewBagNews.GetEnumerator())
using (var likeEnumerator = ViewBagLike.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (newsEnumerator.MoveNext() && likeEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newsEnumerator.Current + " " + likeEnumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: @DomenicRoss - Судя по комментариям и другому ответу, требовалось совсем не то, что указано в заголовке: "Два условия в Foreach". Если это так, напишите, удалю свой ответ.